# A p-adic number is contained in $\mathbb Q$ iff it is periodic.

Tags: number-theory

A p-adic number is contained in $\mathbb Q$ iff it is periodic.

I'm looking at the $\Rightarrow$ direction. I pretty much know the standard proof but I'm given a hint in my assignment which I can't see how it leads on to the rest of the proof.

Hint: Given $a\in\mathbb Q, a\neq0$. Write $a=p^0\frac{t}s$ with $p\nmid ts$ and show that $\exists r>0$ s.t. $1-p^r\equiv 0\pmod{s}$.

I don't even know if I'm correct in getting to the hint but here's what I have so far:
$p\nmid ts$ implies $p\nmid s$. By Euler's Theorem, $p^{\phi(s)}\equiv 1\pmod s$. So $r=\phi(s)>0$.

How can I carry on?

Comment: +1 for showing your progress and thoughts about the problem! Too many people just post their question and expect to get an answer to paste into their homework.

Comment: Mimick the junior high level version of the problem of showing that rational numbers (with denominator coprime to ten) have periodic decimal expansions: you can check that $7\mid 999999$ and can use this to show that
$$\frac17=\frac{142857}{999999}$$ has the familiar decimal expansion of period six.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your work so far is correct. It seems like you're asking about how to conclude that $a$ is periodic in $p$-adic notation. Here is a hint:

Write $1-p^r=sk$ for some integer $k$, so that $a=\dfrac{tk}{1-p^r}$. Now, what is $\dfrac{1}{1-p^r}$ in $p$-adic notation?

Comment: That's just the sum from $1$ to $p^r$. So... $a=tk+tkp+tkp^2+...+tkp^r$ (ie. $a$ is periodic because $a_i=a_1\forall 1\leq i\leq r$). Yes?

Comment: @HaikalYeo In $p$-adic notation, $\frac{1}{1-p^r} = \sum_{i \geq 0} p^{ir} = 1 + p^r + p^{2r}+ \ldots$. Indeed, $(1- p^r) \cdot  \sum_{i \geq 0} p^{ir} = (1-p^r)(1 + p^r + p^{2r}+ \ldots) = 1$.